# What is Ethereum Studio?

Tags: ethereum-studio

I have seen Ethereum Studio from ether.camp recommended in various places, but to download it requires some registration, so I assume it is not open source, although it claims to be based on cloud9. Some people might object against using closed source product for applications that may deal with large sums.

Is it really closed-source? What makes people use it? And being "cloud", does it require constant internet access, and does it save source files in the cloud?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is basically an adapted version of the Cloud9 IDE for Ethereum, with some additional tools:

1. A blockchain emulator called the sandbox, very good for writing automated tests.
2. Oraclize Integration.

It requires internet access since the IDE functionality runs server side on the MS Azure cloud.

Alternatives are:

- Ethereum integration in Visual Studio
- Browser Solidity
- Truffle/Embark/Dapple with your preferred Editor

[image: Ethereum Studio]

Comment: The third alternative for me:) What about the open source bit and forcing (or not) you to save source files to the cloud?

Comment: I had te search: Cloud9 is not open-source and the files are stored in their cloud workspace and you can only download them manually. Both these features in my opinion diminish its suitability for smart contract development.