# What's the relative advantage of using remix.ethereum.org over studio.ethereum.org?

Tags: remix, ide, ethereum-studio

Studio and remix are two web-based IDE that are hosted at ethereum.org. What are the advantages of each? In which situation should they be used each?

Answer (score 2):

Here is main advantage of each ide (maybe i will miss some please let me know):

Studio:

- It support html, css, js and solidity unlike remix which only support smart contract only. (Basicly you can make a full dapp with studio but you can't with remix)
- It can preview your dapp website for you so you can easy see and modify your code quickly
- It is very friendly for new developer (It has README tutorial, template, hides most of the complex thing)
- I really like the layout and the dark theme of its (Change my mind)

You can also check this link: [What is Ethereum Studio?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10988/what-is-ethereum-studio?rq=1).

Remix:

- Not like Studio smart contract, which only support solidity, Remix can support both solidiy and vyper(my personnal favorite).
- It have many plugin so you can tinker with your smart contract code if you know what you are doing.
- You can debug your smart contract while Studio haven't support it
- You choose your own compiler version

Comment: WHat compiler uses Studio? Is the latest by default?

Comment: @Cyril Attie it's the stable release currently i think it is 0.5.11. You can check the version by compile a test and check the output